# How do you make a crystal report from a dataset programmatically

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I have created a dataset and intend to use it in my crystal report but thing is when i preview the data in the dataset i see it but on the crystal report it only shows the column names only and no data shows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can remember when you use VS.net wizard to add crystal report it will create class for the crystal report document (upon your choises in the wizard)

so all what you need to do is to create object from this class which will be the same name of the crystal report document (file) name ,and then call the dataource method and pass your dataset which have your data to this method.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

[Tutorials and Sample Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227881(VS.80).aspx) from MSDN.